# liferay enable organization or community by role

Tags: liferay, organization, role

I am working on a new liferay implementation.  I have all of my users in an external system, and have used the external env. to authenticate through my own authentication system.  I also store roles in this same system.  I have been able to successfully pass these to liferay so that all of my users roles are available in liferay.

I would like to create an organization or community that is associated with a role.  For example if I have a role called 'myusers' in my external system, I would like to tie that role to an organization or community in liferay.  Then when a user logged in to liferay with that role, they would be able to be part of that organization or community.  Is this possible in liferay?  I know it's kind of backwards to the normal flow in liferay of adding roles to users and then adding user to a community or organization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using the expando functionality built into liferay.  Doing this I allow for entering a list of roles that should map to that organization.  This allows me to look at the roles of my users when they login and determine what organizations they should be a member of.  I then programatically add/remove the users from the organizations based upon the roles defined in the expando attribute and the roles assigned to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the below code to check if the user belongs to a role and then add him to the appropriate organization.

To add a user to all Organizations:

```java
public final static void addAllOrganizationstoUser(long userId) throws SystemException, PortalException {
    // gets all organizations
    List<Organization> organizations = OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.getOrganizations(ALL_POS, ALL_POS);
    long[] users = new long[]{userId};
    // register user to orgs
    for (Organization organization : organizations) {
      UserLocalServiceUtil.addOrganizationUsers(organization.getOrganizationId(), users);
    }
}
```